# OSX 10.8.4 xcode Sigabrt

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion

Just got done updating my box to osx 10.8.4 and everything appeared to be functioning fine until I began using xcode. The first time I build a project it runs on the simulator fine. The second time I build the same project I get a sigabrt in main. I tried catching all exceptions but none are being thrown. This happens on existing projects or even brand new ones. I tried 'Reset content and settings' on simulator, rebooting the machine, and cleaning the project. All of which had no effect. Considering re-installing xcode, but wanted to see if anyone else can reproduce or had any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update your Xcode. Xcode 4.6.3 solves the issue.**

If you can't, TUAW has a [solution](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/) (or workaround, however you want to see it).

Comment: Great find. I am just happy to confirm I am not the only one. Saved me an afternoon of pointlessly installing xcode.

Comment: You are not the only one... definitely...